# how to move a file from listview to a directory?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a listview that shows all the audio files in the sd card. Now i want to move  any file from that list to a folder named "Ankit_s" but on running the following code i'm getting an error like this,

```
02-18 10:20:26.980: E/readfile(407): /sdcardasd.mp3 (No such file or directory)
```

My code is in `onListItemClick()`,

```
public class Pick extends ListActivity {


    //Setting SD card path. this is the place from where we retrieve the audio files
        private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        // To hold all songs   
        private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
        //To find out the Index of File, Currently selected one.
        private int currentPosition = 0;


    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user);

        //Below method bind all songs to ListView
        BindAllSongs();


    }

    private void BindAllSongs() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //To hold all the audio files from SDCARD
                File fileListBeforeFiltering = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
                //Filter all the MP# format songs to list out
                //Checking for the MP3 Extension files existence 
                    if (fileListBeforeFiltering.listFiles(new FilterFilesByMp3Extension()).length > 0) 
                    {
                        //Loop thru all the files filtered and fill them in SongsList view that we have 
                        //Defined above.
                        for (File file : fileListBeforeFiltering.listFiles(new FilterFilesByMp3Extension())) 
                        {
                            //Adding all filtered songs to the list
                                songs.add(file.getName());
                        }

                        //Loading them to Listview using ArrayAdapter.

                        ArrayAdapter<String> allsongs = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song_items, songs);
                        setListAdapter(allsongs);
                }

    }

    // Responding to OnClick Event to Listview
    @Override   
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //Hold the currently clicked Item [Sending Path and Current song from list view
        currentPosition = position;




           try {
               File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator+"Ankit_s");

               if(!direct.exists())
                {
                    if(direct.mkdir()); //directory is created;

                }


               File sourcepath = new File(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));


               File fromFile=new File(sourcepath.getName());

               File toFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"Ankit",fromFile.getName());

             java.io.FileInputStream fosfrom = new FileInputStream(fromFile);

             java.io.FileOutputStream fosto = new FileOutputStream(toFile);

             byte bt[] = new byte[1024];

             int c;

             while ((c = fosfrom.read(bt)) > 0) {

             fosto.write(bt, 0, c); 

             }

             Toast.makeText(Pick.this," moved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             fromFile.deleteOnExit();

            fosfrom.close();

            fosto.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            Log.e("readfile", ex.getMessage());

             }
    }  
}
```

anymore suggestions please..

Comment: Do you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission added to your `Manifest.XML`?

Comment: yes i've already given write permission in my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add `/mnt` in the path, hence just edit following line

```
File toFile=new File("/mnt/sdcard/Ankit_s/",fromFile.getName());
```

with

```
File toFile=new File("/sdcard/Ankit_s/",fromFile.getName());
```

Now it will work fine. Also you need to give `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Edit, you need to check whether file is exists or not, if not you need to create new by following syntax,

```
File toFile=new File("/sdcard/Ankit_s/",fromFile.getName());

if ( !toFile.exists() )
{
     toFile.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still i'm getting the same error.

Comment: Still getting the same error bro. I think there might be some problem with the source path.